# TortoiseSVN - not able to differentiate between CR and LF

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a shell script which has got couple lines of ^M removal code. I am checking in these files to SVN through TortoiseSVN on Win 7. But ^M (Which is represented by CR in win) gets converted to LF automatically, ruining my script.

[image: Notepad++ showing CR character]

[image: Tortoise SVN not showing any difference]

There is no eol property set for the file.